# Decode battery values

Tags: android

In the broadcast receiver for battery, I have following 3 lines of code:

```
int health = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_HEALTH, 0);
int plugged = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, 0);
int voltage = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_VOLTAGE, 0);
```

The values for the above three is coming as 2,2 and 4.

How can I decode these values and show something meaningful to the user like for health, can't I some how computer if battery health is good, bad or needs replacement.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Read http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/BatteryManager.html and create your logic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this for battery

```
switch (health) {
    case BatteryManager.BATTERY_HEALTH_DEAD:

        break;
    case BatteryManager.BATTERY_HEALTH_GOOD:

        break;
    case BatteryManager.BATTERY_HEALTH_COLD:

        break;
    case BatteryManager.BATTERY_HEALTH_OVERHEAT:

        break;
    case BatteryManager.BATTERY_HEALTH_OVER_VOLTAGE:

        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
```

use for pluged

```
switch (plugged ) {
    case BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_AC:

        break;
    case BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_USB:

        break;
    case BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_WIRELESS:

        default:
        break;
    }
```

use for voltage

```
switch (voltage) {
    case BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING:

        break;
    case BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_DISCHARGING:

        break;
    case BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_FULL:
        break;
    case BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_NOT_CHARGING:
        break;
    case BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_UNKNOWN:
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Under onCreate method use

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    BroadcastReceiver batteryReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        int scale = -1;
        int level = -1;
        int voltage = -1;
        int temp = -1;
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            level = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
            scale = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);
            temp = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_TEMPERATURE, -1);
            voltage = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_VOLTAGE, -1);
            Log.e("BatteryManager", "level is "+level+"/"+scale+", temp is "+temp+", voltage is "+voltage);
        }
    };
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
    registerReceiver(batteryReceiver, filter);
}
```

If level = 20/100 means battery is 20% remaining
temp is 320 then temperature is 32 degree celcuis.
and if voltage is 4000, then voltage is 4.000 volts